# Java Serialisation : reading and writing to a file

Tags: java

I have a class called `item` which has a few Strings like price, stock etc.

I write these to a file as such:

```
item[] data = new item[numberofitems];
```

The array is then filled then:

```
ObjectOutputStream outinv = new ObjectOutputStream(outinvstream);

    outinv.writeInt(numberofitems);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofitems; i++)
    {

        outinv.writeObject(data[i]);
    }
```

This all works fine. The trouble comes when I try reading it in:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
inventory = (item[]) ois.readObject();
```

where f is the file (it definitely finds it) and inventory is an `item[]`. However I get a `OptionalDataException`

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read in the same order as you write it.You are writing the array size first and therefore you need to read the int first and then your Objects

Comment: Thanks @Kumar Abhinav but how do i read in a .dat file line by line in order to get the ints and the object?

Comment: @John ObjectInputStream.readInt() ,ObjectInputStream implements DataInput which has methods to read primitives